# spring portlet mvc 3 language specific message in controller

Tags: spring, properties, portlet

I am currently working on a spring portlet mvc 3 project. I have a requirement where I need to set a message (which is read from language specific properties file) from inside a controller method.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using annotations or xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add an autowired **ApplicationContext** and then fetch your message via this object